# Exclude child elements from being jQuery selectable?

Tags: jquery-ui

Is it possible to exclude certain child elements from being selected? Right now when I mark something as selectable it makes everything nested beneath a `selectee` which is a little annoying. I can see ways around this of course but it's rather a lot of work and if possible I'd try to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the filter option when initializing. For example, if the selectee is an li element then use the following:

```
$( ".selector" ).selectable({ filter: "li" });
```